# Adding play-json library to my non-play framework SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.5

I am tried to test play-json library in standalone non-play framework SBT project.

I have added below in the plugins.sbt in the SBT project.

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.5.4"
```

I have added the below scala object but it is throwing compilation error

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

import play.api.libs.json.Writes

 object TestObject extends App{

 val jsonObj = Json.obj(
  "id" -> 1
 )
}
```

But, the imports are throwing unresolved dependency compilation error.

[image]

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Have you solved the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct, I have tried locally without any issue.

The only thing that might be causing problems and you might not be aware of is that in sbt files every line must be separated by an empty line if you are using sbt 0.13.6

Any other issues you might have is that IntelliJ has not reloaded the project. 
- Use Syncrhonize for the full project
- In the SBT tab click refresh

The code should work as long as you see the library play-json on the list of libraries bellow de project code.

Enjoy scala.